# Clonar uma struct sem copiar o endereço de memória

Tags: c++, memória, struct, c++-builder

Eu preciso copiar a `struct problema1` para a `struct problema2` , mas ao fazer do jeito que ta no programa abaixo , quando eu altero a `struct problema2` também estar alterando a `struct problema1`. Do jeito que eu fiz to copiando a referencia, queria copiar sem referencia, mas não sei como faz isso.

```
void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{

 struct Tproblem
   {
    TList *Lista;
    float x;
    };

  typedef struct Tproblem Problem;
  Problem *Problema1 ,*Problema2;
  int *x;
  Problema1 = new Problem;
  Problema1->Lista = new TList;
  for( int i = 0 ; i<10; i++)
    {
       x = new int ;
       *x = i;
       Problema1->Lista->Add(x) ;
     }



   Problema2 = new Problem;
    Problema2 = Problema1;// aki eu copia a estrutura


     for( int i = 0 ; i<Problema1->Lista->Count ;i++)
    {
      x = (int*)Problema1->Lista->Items[i];
      ListBox1->Items->Strings[i]=IntToStr(*x);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esse código está copiando o ponteiro, portando o código tem duas variáveis apontando para o mesmo objeto, então alterando um altera o que está apontado no outro. O que precisa é criar um novo objeto e apontar para ele. Isso pode ser feito com [`memcpy()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memcpy). Algo assim:

```
memcpy(Problema2, Problema1, sizeof(Problema1));
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Memory/MemCopy.cpp).

Tem maneiras melhores de resolver isso, mas aí precisaria mexer em todo o código.

Comment: Primeiramente muito obrigado pelo rapido retorno ,  mudei o codigo , usando a funcao memcpy() , mas ao deletar um item do problema 2 , continua deletando um item do problema 1

Comment: Não deve acontecer isto, então estão com outro problema e deve fazer outra pergunta mostrando o que fez. Você não deve modificar a pergunta. Assim você invalida a resposta. O que posso te adiantar é que terá quer fazer o mesmo com o membro `Lista` da estrutura. Vou ressaltar o que já falei antes, isto não é o jeito certo de fazer isto, mas não posso refazer o código todo para você, nem sei se desejaria isto.

Comment: Com isso ele vai copiar o ponteiro da lista, ele deve criar um memcpy para a lista também, não?

Comment: @JoãoSobral isso, sempre que você tem um ponteiro, se copiar o ponteiro está só copiando uma referência para o dado. Quando se quer copiar o dado tem que usar alguma técnica de cópia da memória onde ele está. Esta é uma delas. Na verdade vou repetir, não é assim que se faz em C++.

Comment: Se a cópia desta struct vai ser frequente você pode implementar um método "copy" nesta struct, de forma a automatizar a cópia da lista e da própria struct, possivelmente utilizando o memcpy exemplificado pelo bigown.

Comment: @bigown vou fazer outra pergunta postando o que eu fiz , implementando tambem a funcao memcpy para o mebro lista . obrigado!

Comment: @bigown Infelizmente esta solução não resolve o problema e ainda recomenda a utilização de `memcpy` para copiar estruturas quando a pessoa esta usando C++. O correto e mais simples é utilizar o operador de cópia, seja o padrão ou um definido pelo usuário quando o padrão não for correto, já que assim garantimos que a copia dos membros esta sendo feita de acordo com a intenção de quem criou os tipos, a exceção sendo ponteiros. Nesse caso, deveria-se utilizar `Problema2 = new Problem(*Problema1);` e declarar um construtor de cópia que copia corretamente a lista dentro da estrutura.

Comment: @TiagoGomes eu não recomendo não, falo que não é o ideal. Mas para este código específico achei que era a melhor solução. Você pode discordar, mas não pode dizer que está errado. Ele disse que ia postar outra pergunta, aí eu mostraria outra forma. O código todo está muito ruim para dar solução sofisticada. Criar um construtor de cópia em algo que está sendo declarado dentro de um método, não acha exagerado não? Talvez você não tenha entendido pra que serve este recurso.

Comment: @bigown Não acho exagerado, essa é a função de um construtor de cópia. Mesmo não querendo ser a ideal, a sua solução esta ignorando o que a própria linguagem recomenda para utilizar uma função de C que ignora todo o extra que mesmo o construtor de cópia padrão pode fazer quando necessário. Além disso, sua solução nem é mais simples que a utilização do construtor padrão já que substituir `memcpy(Problema2, Problema1, sizeof(Problema1))` por `Problema2 = new Problem(*Problema1)` teria o mesmo efeito prático nesse caso mas utilizaria a funcionalidade recomendada pela linguagem.

Comment: Mas vai ter que escrever o construtor de cópia para usar uma vez. Eu acho exagero.

Comment: Ele vai ter que escrever o código de cópia de qualquer jeito, seja dentro de um construtor de cópia ou seja solto no meio da função, então porque não escrever no construtor de cópia que é onde a linguagem recomenda e nunca mais se preocupar com isso se por algum motivo ele precisar copiar isso de novo ?

Comment: Recomendações são chamadas assim, porque tem que analisar o contexto, neste não há necessidade. Seguir recomendações cegamente não serve para nada. Se você tivesse me dado um motivo plausível eu mudaria a resposta. O que ocorre aqui é uma diferença de cultura. Você segue recomendações, eu sigo o que é mais prático para a situação específica. Em outra situações eu faria o que você está falando. Se um dia ele tiver que mudar (não parece ser o caso, afinal é só um exercício) ele terá que mudar o código de forma mais ampla, como eu coloquei na resposta. Atendi a necessidade dele e orientei o certo

Comment: Sim, concordo com seu pragmatismo mas acredito que nesse caso ele não faz sentido pelo simples fato de não ser uma solução mais simples nem mais correta que a solução escolhida pela própria linguagem. Como dito no outro comentário, sua linha de código na resposta pode ser substituída, e até removendo outra linha, por uma linha de código que tem o mesmo efeito e de mesmo tamanho: `Problema2 = new Problem(*Problema1)`. Não vejo qual o motivo plausível ou a vantagem de utilizar uma solução alternativa a proposta pela própria linguagem nesse caso, principalmente ao responder dúvidas de iniciantes.